# Google spreadsheet search list from bottom to up

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following matrix:

```
A             B
1 B111         YES
2 B112         YES
3 B113         NO
4 B111         YES
```

I need a formula that searches for the last input of an element in A to show its correspondent of B in another cell.

Something like: search in A B111; SHOW B= YES

Comment: Excel is different to Google Sheets. Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in row 1 (any column apart from A or B):

```
=index(B:B,max(if(A:A<>"",row(A:A))))
```